# Solving for an implicit function numerically?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, implicit-function

I am trying to come up with a systematic way for solving an implicit "functional" equation. That is, given

$$g(x) = f(x + a \cdot f(x))$$

how would one (numerically) recover the **functional** form of $f(x)$? $g(x)$ is known and *a* is a known constant. I've been thinking of defining something along the lines of

$$h \equiv g(x) - f(x+ a \cdot f(x))$$

and using something like Newton-Raphson's method to find the zeros of $h$ as a function of $f$, but that doesn't quite seem to work, because for that I would need $f(x)$ and not $f(x+a \cdot f(x))$ to appear in my $h$.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: With smoothness assumptions, you might be able to determine $f$ near its zeroes. Every zero of $f$ is also a zero of $g$, so if we boldly assume the converse, we *may* be able to find something interesting from finding the zeroes of $g$ and trying to determine $f$ near that (e.g., try to look for a Taylor expansion)

Comment: Thanks Hagen. That's an interesting approach, and physically-speaking your converse assumption can be justified (this equation has a physical origin which I didn't introduce for the sake of brevity), but the approach only works close to the zeros ... When I started looking into this I was very surprised I couldn't find any methods for solving for the functional form of an implicit function!